# Successfully mosaicking rasters in R, but the analysis is not showing values

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, mosaic, rasterstats

I am mosaicking three rasters together. The raster are mosaicking together successfully and will plot but any analysis of the rasters returns NA.  Here is the code:

```
import <- raster("USGS_13_n39w120_20230308.tif")
import1 <- raster("USGS_13_n39w121_20220206.tif")
import2 <- raster("USGS_13_n40w120_20230308.tif")
##Returns the range of values in this raster--works!
range(values(import))
rstList <- list(import, import1, import2)
rstList$fun <- mean
C_raster <- mosaic(import, import1, import2, fun = mean)

##plotting the merged raster works (see below)
plot(C_raster)
##Only returns NA
range(values(C_raster))
```

[image]

Any ideas why the data is plottable but will not return a value on the range(values(C_raster) call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only 3 out of 4 tiles in your mosaic, 1/4 of the mosaic are NA values. By default, `range` doesn't exclude NA's, so add `na.rm = TRUE`

```
range(values(C_raster), na.rm = TRUE)
```

You can also check raster's properties, but first compute statistics:

```
C_raster <- setMinMax(C_raster)
```